# lightning-vertical-navigation - is this right way to implement

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Please help, Is this the right way to implement.

HTML:

```
<template>
<div style="min-width: 225px; border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;">
    <lightning-layout>
        <lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-vertical-navigation selected-item={selectedItem} onselect={handleSelect} class="navigation">
                <lightning-vertical-navigation-section>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Recently Viewed" name="reports_recent"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Private Reports" name="reports_private"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="Public Reports" name="reports_public"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                    <lightning-vertical-navigation-item label="All Reports" name="reports_all"></lightning-vertical-navigation-item>
                </lightning-vertical-navigation-section>                    
            </lightning-vertical-navigation>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item padding="around-medium">               
            <template if:true={recentlyviewed}>
            <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                These are the Recently Viewed!
            </div>
        </template>
         <template if:true={privatereport}>
            <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                These are the Private Reports!
            </div>
        </template>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</div>
```

Js:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class LightningExampleVerticalNavAdvanced extends LightningElement {
@track selectedItem = 'reports_private';
@track currentContent = 'reports_private';
@track updatedCount = 12;
recentlyviewed = false;
privatereport =false;

handleSelect(event) {
    const selected = event.detail.name; 
    alert(selected)        ;
    this.currentContent = selected;
    if (selected =='reports_recent'){
        this.recentlyviewed = true;
    }else{
        this.recentlyviewed = false;
    }
    if (selected =='reports_private'){
        this.privatereport = true;
    }else{
        this.privatereport = false;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some feedback on your implementation:

1. you only need one attribute/property on your class and that's `selectedItem` so remove the others. Instead, add getters to return booleans on whether `selectedItem === 'reports_recent'` etc... and use those in expressions in your template tags.
2. you don't need `@track` for your attributes
3. replace the code in `handleSelect` by just `this.selectedItem = event.detail.name;`