# I don't know how to put my JavaScript code in an LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, navigation-menu

I'm new on Salesforce and I'm trying to set up a custom navigation bar with an LWC. The problem is that I have my code in JavaScript, but I don't know how to place it in the navbar.js
If somebody could tell me what is wrong or recommend an article or trail, I would greatly appreciate it.

I create a LWC called navbar:

**My navbar.html**

```
<header id="header" class="header">
    <nav id="navbar" class="navbar nav-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#hero" class="nav-link scrollto active"><lightning-icon icon-name="utility:home" size="x-small" class="lightning-icon"></lightning-icon> <span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="nav-link scrollto"><lightning-icon icon-name="utility:user" size="x-small" class="lightning-icon"></lightning-icon> <span>About</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume" class="nav-link scrollto"><lightning-icon icon-name="utility:page" size="x-small" class="lightning-icon"></lightning-icon><span>Resume</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link scrollto"><lightning-icon icon-name="utility:notebook" size="x-small" class="lightning-icon"></lightning-icon> <span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" class="nav-link scrollto"><lightning-icon icon-name="utility:cases" size="x-small" class="lightning-icon"></lightning-icon> <span>Services</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="nav-link scrollto"><lightning-icon icon-name="utility:email" size="x-small" class="lightning-icon"></lightning-icon>  <span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
</header><!-- End Header -->
```

**My navbar.js**

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class Navbar extends LightningElement {

  /**
   * Easy selector helper function
   */
  const select = (el, all = false) => {
    el = el.trim()
    if (all) {
      return [...document.querySelectorAll(el)]
    } else {
      return document.querySelector(el)
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy event listener function
   */
  const on = (type, el, listener, all = false) => {
    let selectEl = select(el, all)
    if (selectEl) {
      if (all) {
        selectEl.forEach(e => e.addEventListener(type, listener))
      } else {
        selectEl.addEventListener(type, listener)
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Easy on scroll event listener 
   */
  const onscroll = (el, listener) => {
    el.addEventListener('scroll', listener)
  }

  /**
   * Navbar links active state on scroll
   */
  let navbarlinks = select('#navbar .scrollto', true)
  const navbarlinksActive = () => {
    let position = window.scrollY + 200
    navbarlinks.forEach(navbarlink => {
      if (!navbarlink.hash) return
      let section = select(navbarlink.hash)
      if (!section) return
      if (position >= section.offsetTop && position <= (section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight)) {
        navbarlink.classList.add('active')
      } else {
        navbarlink.classList.remove('active')
      }
    })
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', navbarlinksActive)
  onscroll(document, navbarlinksActive)
}
```

Comment: [Lightning Web Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics) Trailheads would be the best place to start learning LWC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`there are a lot of things that needs to be updated in your code`.
So for your case **you can check next articles** :

- Vertical Navigation  : [lightning-vertical-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-vertical-navigation/example)
- Vertical Navigation Lightning Design System : [vertical-navigation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/vertical-navigation/)
- Build a vertical navigation : [build-list-of-links-navigation-in-lwc](https://www.w3web.net/build-list-of-links-navigation-in-lwc/)
- another question about it :  [lightning-vertical-navigation-is-this-right-way-to-implement](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295134/lightning-vertical-navigation-is-this-right-way-to-implement)